# Why R function Chol() breaks for Hilbert matrices of order n > 12

Tags: r, numerics, cholesky-decomposition

Is there any theoretical reason that Chol() in R breaks for Hilbert matrix of order greater than 12?

Thanks,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Zen's comment and F.Tusell's answer are correct (+1 to both). Just to add a bit on this: If you look at the associated eigenvalues of `Hilbert(13)` for a example, the smallest of them is smaller in scale than `.Machine$double.eps` which is roughly 2.2e-16. Therefore this eigenvalue (and others of even smaller scale) is regarded as a machine zero and leads the decomposition algorithm to treat `Hilbert(13+)` as non-positive definite matrix and thus not having a Cholesky decomposition. (So actually $H(13-15)$ are "semi-PD" numerically speaking, and for $H(16+)$ you even end up with "*negative zeros*" eigenvalues).

Answer (score 3):

Hilbert matrices are of notorious poor condition, which probably account for the failure you are seeing.